# Errors updating table contents with Prototype

Tags: javascript, html-table, prototypejs, innerhtml

I want to do something like this in Prototype:

```
onSuccess: function(transport) {
    template = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
    form = event.up('form');
    form.select('.audio_channels').update(template.channelHtml);
}
```

The form tag is a table, and I want to replace its contents. `channelHtml` is a string of HTML `<tr>` tags.

I'm getting:

> `TypeError`: Object `[object HTMLTableElement]` has no method 'update'

So I figure it's not an extended object and tried `Element.extend(form.select('audio_channels'))`, which returns an empty object. Then I try `form.select('.audio_channels').innerHTML(template.channelHtml)` and I get `TypeError: Object [object HTMLTableElement] has no method 'innerHTML'`. Then I try with the tbody element and I get `[object HTMLTableSectionElement] has no method 'innerHtml'`

This seems to me like it should work. `form.select('audio_channels')` is returning the correct DOM element. What do I need to do to set the content of the table based on my ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the last line with

```
form.select('.audio_channels').each(function(node){
  node.update(template.channelHtml);
});
```

That will execute the code on the actual element instead of a one-item array as the original code was doing.